# Can Kafka insert deleted record into sink database to serve as an audit history?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'd like to use kafka to get a deleted record, and insert it into a table in Sink database (and also to update a Delete flag column as true in Sink database)

In my source table, if :

1. new record = insert new record into Sink
2. update record = insert new record into Sink
3. delete record (remove row from table) = insert new record into Sink (and update DeleteFlag column as true)

Can this be done? I will be using debezium with parameters SOURCE mysql to SINK mysql.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the standard Kafka connector to achieve this. I don't think it is possible out of the box.
If a new record comes, kafka will insert a new record. However, in case of update it will replace the older record. And to handle delete you need to generate a kafka message with the same key and `null` value.

However, you can write your own MySQL Connector by extending the kafka connector to simulate the behavior. It is absolutely possible.

Comment: Hi, appreciate your reply. I'm new to Kafka is there a sample that I can refer to that can achieve similar objective?

Comment: Sure. Here are some useful links
https://www.confluent.io/blog/create-dynamic-kafka-connect-source-connectors/ 
https://opencredo.com/blogs/kafka-connect-source-connectors-a-detailed-guide-to-connecting-to-what-you-love/
https://hackernoon.com/writing-your-own-sink-connector-for-your-kafka-stack-fa7a7bc201ea